# Ruby - Sum all keys from a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following hash and I want to sum all total. Using dig I'm able to get the first index. But there are sometimes more keys based on range. How can I sum all amount values?

`results_by_time` has 3 amount keys.

```
value = {
  :next_page_token=>nil,
  :group_definitions=>nil,
  :results_by_time=>[
    {
      :time_period=>{
        :start=>"2022-10-01",
        :end=>"2022-11-01"
      },
      :total=>{
        "BlendedCost"=>{
          :amount=>"49.1803785401",
          :unit=>"USD"
        }
      },
      :groups=>[],
      :estimated=>false
    },
    {
      :time_period=>{
        :start=>"2022-11-01",
        :end=>"2022-12-01"
      },
      :total=>{
        "BlendedCost"=>{
          :amount=>"79.0698396954",
          :unit=>"USD"
      }
    },
    :groups=>[],
    :estimated=>false
  },
  {
    :time_period=>{
      :start=>"2022-12-01",
      :end=>"2022-12-03"
    },
    :total=>{
      "BlendedCost"=>{
        :amount=>"2.6918272089",
        :unit=>"USD"
      }
    },
    :groups=>[],
    :estimated=>true
  }
  ],
  :dimension_value_attributes=>[]
}
```

Here is the dig method but it can only be used to get specific index.

```
amount = value.dig(:results_by_time, 0, :total, 'BlendedCost', :amount).to_f

print amount
```

Comment: how about iterating over `results_by_time` to fetch amount then do sum => `amount = value[:results_by_time].map{ |i| i.dig(:total, 'BlendedCost', :amount) }.sum(&:to_f)`

Comment: @SampatBadhe one thing to watch out for is that if `i.dig(:total, 'BlendedCost', :amount)` returns any nils you'll get an error. Use `.map{ ... }.compact.sum(&:to_f)` or `i.dig(:total, 'BlendedCost', :amount) || 0` to avoid it.

Comment: @max yes, I have used `&to_f` which will convert `nil` to `0` before applying `sum`

Comment: My edit was merely to reformat the example hash so that it could be read more easily.